# Image not appearing in Heroku production

Tags: html, heroku

My image works locally, but I pushed it to heroku and it's not appearing.

A few other ones didn't appear either, but I fixed that issue (it was due to capitalization of the .png titles and HTML files).  However, the syntax is perfectly fine here.

```
 <img class="thumbnail" src="images/logo_instagram.png" alt="">
```

The path is images/logo_instagram.png

[image]

Comment: Look at Firebug's "Net" tab. What is the exact URL being called? You are using a relative image path that might not work in your on-line scenario.

Comment: sure you added the image into git?

Comment: @Manuel The newly renamed image ins't getting pushed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, even after several pushes to git, renaming the logo_Instagram.png(capitalized) will not downcase and show up in git downcased, so I went to my pages and edited the source to retrieve the file from logo_Instagram(capitalized) instead to sidestep the situation, and now it appears.